# Rename a .part file into CSV via FTP

Tags: php, csv, ftp, rename

I need a PHP that finds files that come into a folder and rename them. I have been able to write the script so that it rename a file while a do it manually. However, I cannot figure out how to correctly run the file process when the .part files are dropped into the folder by the Warehouse Management System. It is required to fetch the part files that come every hour and save it into a folder inside the same FTP as CSV.

I have gone from simple to complex coding. The built-in function [rename()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename) seemed to be exactly what I needed but it did not work.

Then I tried with [fopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php) because it suits even more the requirements, but I did not manage to run it at all.

The part files need to be converted into CSV first, and then joined by a common ID to add information to the first file. Although, it would be enough to have them separately.

This is the PHP file running rename() working locally but not on the FTP:

```
    <?php
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);

$file = 'ftp://username:passwordq@ftpdomain.com/';
$fp = fopen($file, 'w');

rename(startsWith($file, dirname(__FILE__)."/Prod*"), "/Plytix/Prod*.{csv}");
?>
```

After @brombeer reply I tried this:

```
<?php
$path = './'; // To get all the files in the folder that...
$part_file = glob($path.'/*.part'); // ... have part as extension
//$part_file = 'somefile.txt.bak';
$csv_file = $part_file . '.csv';

// set up basic connection
$ftp_server = "ftp.domain.com";
$ftp = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($ftp, 'username', 'password');

// try to rename $part_file to $csv_file
if (ftp_rename($ftp, $part_file, $csv_file)) {
 echo "successfully renamed $part_file to $csv_file\n";
} else {
 echo "There was a problem while renaming $part_file to $csv_file\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($ftp);
?>
```

Comment: When you say "it did not work" what do you mean by that? Do you get an error? What error? And while I'm not sure about PHP and its abstractions, `rename` usually renames on the local system not on remote systems (like over FTP). And what is this `startsWith` function? Is it something similar to the one [shown here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-startswith-and-endswith-functions/) which deals with *strings* and not files?

Comment: PHP has a [book on FTP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) and the functions you can use. [ftp\_rename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rename.php) seems to be more suitable

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude! I used [startswith](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-starts-with.php) because the files start with that name but then is followed by a timestamp. In that way, the file would be processed despite the timestamp. That was the idea :)

Comment: Thanks @brombeer! I did not know about it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Answering your question. No, I did not observe any error, just that it did not renamed the file into CSV.

Comment: *"After @brombeer reply I tried this"* – And? Did it work? Anyway, the `glob` seems suspicious. Are you trying to looks for local or remote files? If remote, then it won't work. Btw, where is the PHP code running?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Hello again! No, it did not work for me. The files are local. The .part files (essentially CSV files using pipes) are coming into the FTP folder from an ERP system (remote), processed by a cron PHP file and then unlinked. The PHP code is run on the FTP server, where the .part files are uploaded into a specific folder and the website root folder. Thanks for your time and valuable knowledge sharing!

Comment: If the files are local, then your question is not about "FTP". You have started all wrong.